# PHP get some parts from shell_exec

Tags: php, curl, terminal, shell-exec

I need your help guys i have some php code running on my server:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['id'])
$id = $_GET['id'];
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $id);
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    $stream = $data['link'];
    $url    = $stream;



$output = shell_exec ('curl -I -L ' . $url);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

and it outputs this when i go to:http://146.185.137.252/new.php?id=HgzGwKwLmgM

it outputs this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Sat, 11 Feb 2017 01:25:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=db002cf41b2472eb20de42ec65b16029a1486776356; expires=Sun, 11-Feb-18 01:25:56 GMT; path=/; domain=.youtubeinmp3.com; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38
Location: //w23.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?id=HgzGwKwLmgM&r=kT7YFcbHgX3m25ULP3GeWulVx9OmT2qd&t=Queen+-+Don%27t+Stop+Me+Now+%28Official+Video%29
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 32f40283e57d148b-AMS

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 11 Feb 2017 01:25:56 GMT
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Content-Length: 3499136
Last-Modified: Fri, 18 Nov 2016 18:09:22 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Queen - Don't Stop Me Now (Official Video).mp3"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Expires: 0
ETag: "582f43d2-356480"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

but i don't need al that stuff i only need to two things:
the (Location:) and the (Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=)

in two different variables so in this case i need:

//w23.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?id=HgzGwKwLmgM&r=kT7YFcbHgX3m25ULP3GeWulVx9OmT2qd&t=Queen+-+Don%27t+Stop+Me+Now+%28Official+Video%29

and

Queen - Don't Stop Me Now (Official Video) (i dont want the .mp3 btw)

i've searched the web everywhere but to be honest i'm a total noob at this
so if anyone can help me out that would be amazing

Comment: You could just use a preg_match : preg_match('(Location:.*)', $output, $result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is tested.  Response was copied from my Browser.

I just used curl to do the curl request and used `curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL)` to get the redirect link.

I also added getting the header which you do not need unless there are issues and you'd like to see the response header.

### PHP

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/plain');
$id='HgzGwKwLmgM';
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $id);
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$url = $json['link'];
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$header = curl_exec($ch);
$link = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
echo "\nLINK:  $link\n\nHEADER: $header";

?>
```

### RESPONSE:

```
LINK:  http://w23.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?id=HgzGwKwLmgM&r=aRDQ1MGdfkY3Mm6EFxQqEVqgd9FHf81q&t=Queen+-+Don%27t+Stop+Me+Now+%28Official+Video%29

HEADER: HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Sun, 12 Feb 2017 16:23:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d27df4bad722b0449b88b37d4b9d9b7341486916619; expires=Mon, 12-Feb-18 16:23:39 GMT; path=/; domain=.youtubeinmp3.com; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38
Location: //w23.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?id=HgzGwKwLmgM&r=aRDQ1MGdfkY3Mm6EFxQqEVqgd9FHf81q&t=Queen+-+Don%27t+Stop+Me+Now+%28Official+Video%29
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 330162e8b07e115f-DFW
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the filename and the the title as you wrote on your question.

you can simply use them like this

```
$link = $data['link'];
$title = $data['title'];
```

once you have that, you can print it or make a link with it like this

```
echo "<a href=$link>$title</a>";
```

Unless you want to save the file, you don't need the curl (and the shell_Exec) part

it would look something like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $json = file_get_contents('http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $id);
  $data = json_decode($json, true);

  $link = $data['link'];
  $title = $data['title'];

  echo "<a href=$link>$title</a>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: to see working sample: [click here](http://simplemx.net/video.php?id=HgzGwKwLmgM)

Comment: i need t use curl to follow the redirect to get the direct link